# How to override the version numbers from Spring Boot when importing a BOM pom?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-bom

How do I override the version numbers being imported by Spring Boot, without manually setting each artifact in the dependency management section?

```xml
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.1</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

However, when I run

```
mvn dependency:tree "-Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.*" -Dverbose
```

the output

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dpt-domain-core 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dpt-domain-core ---
[INFO] net.initech.dpt:dpt-domain-core:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO]    +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

Where `2.8.10` is the value of `jackson.version` that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.7.RELEASE:pom` defines.

However, if I explicitly add

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to my *dependency **management*** section, then it resolves correctly to:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dpt-domain-core 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dpt-domain-core ---
[INFO] org.autodatacorp.dpt:dpt-domain-core:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which is perplexing, since that seems like it should be the equivalent of doing an `import` of `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.1:pom` should be the *equivalent* of pasting the contents of that code into manually.

I even tried

```xml
<dependency>                                                                                  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>                                               
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>                                         
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>                                                 
    <exclusions>                                                                              
        <exclusion>                                                                           
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>                                          
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>                                              
        </exclusion>                                                                          
    </exclusions>                                                                             
    <type>pom</type>                                                                          
    <scope>import</scope>                                                                     
</dependency>
```

but with no effect.

---

PS - incase it matters, the Maven I am using is:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: If you want to override the only options are either `dependencies` or `dependencyManagement`. Overriding a property won't work, that will only work when using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any way to get my Jackson BOM import to trump Spring Boot?

Comment: You could try switching the order. Also excluding the bom on spring boot won't matter as afaik spring doesn't use the bom.

Comment: Whats incorrect in explicitly overriding the version of the dependency? Could you explain *equivalent of doing an import of com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.1:pom* ?

Comment: Are you able to use the Spring Boot Parent POM vs. the BOM?

Comment: @nullpointer I don't want to have to specify each artifact from the `jackson-bom` that might be used somewhere in the project or by any of my dependencies.

Comment: @ArtB you would override what you want to, nothing other than that.

Comment: @nullpointer I want to override all Jackson files to be version 2.9.1

Comment: @ArtB, In that case, did you try stating a property with the same name as in the bom with different value (2.9.1)?

Comment: Also, make sure since you are using Java 9 with `maven`, you must use updated versions of the plugins as listed [Java+9+-+Jigsaw](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) as compatible with the latest java version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. You can re-order your BOM imports and this will work. Place Jackson BOM before the Spring Boot BOM. Quick example https://github.com/Flaw101/gsonconverter/blob/feature/jackson_override/pom.xml
2. If you use the Spring Boot Parent POM you just need to override their property `jackson.version` to override versions of other frameworks/libraries

This is also documented by Spring Boot,

https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html

A couple of additional links,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-parent-pom

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

Comment: A page specifically about this: https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about 1. ? It works but i don't understand why the order matters

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html talks about this in detail, but essentially its just how maven dependency resolution works

Answer (score 10):

Adding `jackson-bom.version` to your properties section of the pom.xml file should update jackson dependencies. This will override jackson version in the Spring Boot Parent POM.

```
<properties>
    <jackson-bom.version>2.12.1</jackson-bom.version>
</properties>
```

Using `jackson.version` is not going to work. Please see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17808