# package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jackson, lib

I'm trying to do `mvn clean install` and I'm getting the below error. How can I resolve this, I even tried `mvn clean install -U` but it doesn't work at all. This is a java lib which add as a dependency for my main java project which is running in tomcat server.

**package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation does not exist**

My pom.xml file as below,

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.10.0</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Simply add both dependencies and remove the version in your dependencies because it's already defined via the bom file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need the jackson-databind dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure why you are manipulating the Jackson versions. Only necessary if you do not want to use the version specified in the springboot-starter-parent. The following is sufficient to use the spring recommended Jackson version. Note no version mentioned:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you need to use another version of Jackson all you need is the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475554/how-to-override-the-version-numbers-from-spring-boot-when-importing-a-bom-pom):

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.10.0</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Nobody ever said this was a Spring or Spring Boot project. The only thing the question states is that it's an application running in Tomcat.